# Como mostrar una imagen con diferentes id dentro de un foreach y jquery

Tags: php, jquery, img

No sé como colocarle en el titulo, pero mi problema es que uso un foreach para imprimir una cantidad de datos y que se me repita las card. Necesito mostrar una imagen dando click en cualquier imagen de las diferentes card que trae. Por el momento me funciona el jquery solo con la primer card que me trae, las demás no me funciona. Adjunto el codigo.

```
 <?php foreach ($validar as $v) { ?>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="blog_post lyf">
         <div class="img_podcconu">
             <img class="imgpcard" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/890901007387025408/oztASP4n.jpg" alt="random image">
          </div>
          <div class="container_copy">
             <h3 class="h3card"><?= $v->nombre ?> <?= $v->apellido1 ?></br>
             <i class="mdi mdi-email-variant"></i><?= $v->correo ?> </br>
             <i class="mdi mdi-cellphone-android"></i><?= $v->celular ?> </br>
             <i class="mdi mdi-account-multiple"></i><?= $v->user ?>
             </h3></br>
             <h1 class="h1card">Identificacion</h1>
               <div class="espf">

                  <img id="myImg1" src="<?= base_url() ?>asset/images/confirmacion/<?= $v->img_cedula_front ?>" alt="Snow" style="width:100px;max-width:300px">
                  <img id="myImg2" src="<?= base_url() ?>asset/images/confirmacion/<?= $v->img_cedula_back ?>" alt="Snow" style="width:100px;max-width:300px">
                  <img id="myImg3" src="<?= base_url() ?>asset/images/confirmacion/<?= $v->img_selfie ?>" alt="Snow" style="width:100px;max-width:300px">

              </div>


             <div style="float: right;">
             <button class="btn_primarycard btnc3">Aprobar</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-outline-danger">Danger</button>
            </div>

          </div>

       </div>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

y este es el jquery que me hace el proceso

```
           $("#myImg1").on("click", function() {
            id = $(this).attr("src");
            $('#myModal').show(); //muestro mediante id
            $('#img01').attr("src",id);
        });
        $("#myImg2").on("click", function() {
            id = $(this).attr("src");
            $('#myModal').show(); //muestro mediante id
            $('#img01').attr("src",id);
        });
        $("#myImg3").on("click", function() {
            id = $(this).attr("src");
            $('#myModal').show(); //muestro mediante id
            $('#img01').attr("src",id);
        });
```

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: estas repitiendo la imagen: `<img class="imgpcard" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/890901007387025408/oztASP4n.jpg" alt="random image">`

Comment: Tambien estas repitiendo los id, por ejemplo en tu foreach las veces que se ejecute generar siempre `<img id="myImg1"...` lo mismo con las otras tres: `<img id="myImg2"...` y  `<img id="myImg3"...` de tal manera esto es un error tanto de html que dice que lo id no se deben repetir; como de logica ... ya que tu javascript buscara y mostrara siempre el primer id que encuentre que haga match ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloqué todo dentro del foreach para así mismo poder identificar y colocar diferentes id

```
 <?php foreach ($validar as $v) { ?>


    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
       <div class="blog_post lyf">
          <div class="img_podcconu">
              <img class="imgpcard" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/890901007387025408/oztASP4n.jpg" alt="random image">
          </div>
          <div class="container_copy">
             <h3 class="h3card"><?= $v->nombre ?> <?= $v->apellido1 ?></br>
                 <i class="mdi mdi-email-variant"></i><?= $v->correo ?> </br>
                 <i class="mdi mdi-cellphone-android"></i><?= $v->celular ?> </br>
                 <i class="mdi mdi-account-multiple"></i><?= $v->user ?>
              </h3></br>
              <h1 class="h1card">Identificacion</h1>
              <div class="espf">

                  <img id="myImg<?= $v->id ?>" src="<?= base_url() ?>asset/images/confirmacion/<?= $v->img_cedula_front ?>" alt="Snow" style="width:100px;max-width:300px">
                  <img id="image<?= $v->id ?>" src="<?= base_url() ?>asset/images/confirmacion/<?= $v->img_cedula_back ?>" alt="Snow" style="width:100px;max-width:300px">
                  <img id="tercer<?= $v->id ?>" src="<?= base_url() ?>asset/images/confirmacion/<?= $v->img_selfie ?>" alt="Snow" style="width:100px;max-width:300px">
              <!-- The Modal -->
                  <div id="myModal<?= $v->id ?>" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="vcenter" aria-hidden="true">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                         <img class="modal-content" id="img<?= $v->id ?>">
                       </div>
                    </div>
               <script>
                   $("#myImg<?= $v->id ?>").on("click", function() {
                   id = $(this).attr("src");
                   $('#myModal<?= $v->id ?>').show(); //muestro mediante id
                   $('#img<?= $v->id ?>').attr("src", id);
                  });
                    $("#image<?= $v->id ?>").on("click", function() {
                    id = $(this).attr("src");
                    $('#myModal<?= $v->id ?>').show(); //muestro mediante id
                     $('#img<?= $v->id ?>').attr("src", id);
                     });
                     $("#tercer<?= $v->id ?>").on("click", function() {
                        id = $(this).attr("src");
                        $('#myModal<?= $v->id ?>').show(); //muestro mediante id
                        $('#img<?= $v->id ?>').attr("src", id);
                       });
                  </script>
                 </div>

               </div>


                 <div style="float: right;">
                <button class="btn_primarycard btnc3">Aprobar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-outline-danger">Danger</button>
              </div>

             </div>

             </div>
          <?php } ?>
```